# Expecation of $S(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(X_i+T_i)^2$ for Poisson process $N(t)$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, expected-value, poisson-process

Let $$S(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{N(t)}(X_i+T_i)^2$$ where $N(t)$ is a homogenous Poisson process with rate $\lambda=2$, $X_i$ iid with density $f(x)=e^{-x},x\geq0$ and $T_i$ are the arrival times of $N(t)$. $T_i$ and $X_i$ are independent.

> I want to determine $\mathbb E[S(t)]$.

We have $\mathbb E[X_i]=1$, $\mathbb E[X_i^2]=2$.

> How do can I evaluate $\mathbb E[T_i]$ and $\mathbb E[T_i^2]$?

The final result for $\mathbb E[S(t)]$ shoud be $\mathbb E[S(t)]=\mathbb E[N(t)]\Big(\mathbb E[X_i^2]+2\mathbb E[X_i]\mathbb E[T_i]+\mathbb E[T_i^2]\Big)=2(2+2\mathbb E[T_i]+\mathbb E[T_i^2]\Big)=??$

Comment: How do you get the first equality $\mathbb{E}[S(t)] = \mathbb{E}[N(t)] \left(\ldots\right)$? It seems to me like you used that $N(t)$ and $X_i+T_i$ are independent which is not necessarily true. That said, if you are just looking for the first and second moment of $T_i$ then simply recall that $T_i$ is Gamma distributed as the sum of independent exponential random variables.

Comment: @Michh Does $T_i \sim Gamma(i,\lambda)$ also hold true if the process would be non-homogenous?